# When the before value is not 1 then impute the before value in place of current value until next non 1 value is found in R

Tags: r

The input vector is as below,
`data=c(1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,12,1,1,2,1,1,1)`

I want the output as `1,1,1,1,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,2,2,2,2` where the 1's proceeding the non 1's should be imputed the non 1 value in R.

I tried the following code

```
data=c(1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,12,1,1,2,1,1,1)
sapply(data, function(x) ifelse (lag(x)!=1,lag(x),x))
```

but it didn't yield expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert every `1` after the first non-`1` value to NA then use `zoo::na.locf()`:

```
library(zoo)

x <- c(1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,12,1,1,2,1,1,1)

data[seq_along(x) > which.max(x!= 1) & x== 1] <- NA
na.locf(x)

[1]  1  1  1  1 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12  2  2  2  2
```

Or using `replace()` to add the `NA` values:

```
na.locf(replace(x, seq_along(x) > which.max(x != 1) & x == 1, NA))
```

In response to your comment about applying it to groups, you can use `ave()`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(x, rev(x)), grp = rep(1:2, each = length(x)))

ave(df$x, df$grp, FUN = function(y)
    na.locf(replace(y, seq_along(y) > which.max(y != 1) & y == 1, NA))
)
```

Comment: please help me understand how this code works in conjunction with group by of values from another column

Answer (score 2):

You can write your custom fill function:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,12,1,1,2,1,1,1)

myfill <- function(x) {
  mem <- x[1]
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[i] == 1) {
      x[i] <- mem
    } else {
      mem <- x[i]
    }
  }
  x
}
myfill(x)
# 1  1  1  1 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12  2  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match unique `1` and non-`1` values with the `cumsum` of non-`1` values.

```
(c(1, x[x != 1]))[match(cumsum(x != 1), 0:3)]
# [1]  1  1  1  1 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12  2  2  2  2
```

---

*Data*

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rle` from *base* to overwrite `1` with the value before.

```
x <- rle(data)
y <- c(FALSE, (x$values == 1)[-1])
x$values[y]  <- x$values[which(y)-1]
inverse.rle(x)
# [1]  1  1  1  1 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12  2  2  2  2
```